# Excluir registro do banco com php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Existe alguma maneira de excluir o registro do banco sem que tenha que abrir uma nova pagina ? Neste codigo está direcionando para uma pagina que eu não tenho, ou então, qual maneira correta de ter o arquivo deleta_usuario.php para que exclua somente o registro retornado ?

```
            <?php
                    include('banco/banco.php');
                    @$nome = $_POST['busca_nome_usuario'];                      
                    if($nome == ""){
                        $sql = "select codigo,upper(nome),grupo from usuarios";
                    }else{
                        $nome = strtoupper($nome);  
                        $sql = "select codigo, upper(nome),grupo from usuarios where nome like upper ('%".$nome."%')";
                    }   
                    $exec= mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());
                    $rowli = mysqli_num_rows($exec);
                    $pesq_codigo = "";
                    $grupo = "";
                        while($registros = mysqli_fetch_row ($exec)){
                            if($registros[2] == 'A'){
                                $grupo = "ADM";
                            }else if($registros[2] == 'F'){
                                $grupo = "FNC";
                            }else if($registros[2] == 'C'){
                                $grupo = "CNJ";
                            }
                            echo("<tr><td>".$registros[0]."</td><td>".$registros[1]."</td>
                                      <td>".$grupo."</td>
                                      <td><a href='editar_usuario.php?id=".$registros[0]."' class='btn btn-warning'>EDITAR</a></td>
                                      <td><a href='delete_usuario.php?id=".$registros[0]."' onclick="return confirm('Tem certeza que deseja deletar este registro?')"' class='btn btn-danger'>EXCLUIR</a></td></tr>");
                        }
                    mysqli_close($link);
```

Answer (score -2):

Para que seja possivel utilizar o delete sem abrir uma nova aba, você deverá utilizar requisições AJAX.

O que é ajax?
Acesse o artigo: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Resumindo, o `AJAX` irá acessar o link `delete_usuario.php` passando `ID` como `POST` sem que o usuario veja as requisições. Não é aconselhavel manter o ID para deletar recebendo como GET ( Qualquer um pode editar a URL e excluir outras ID ).

Crie um evento de `onClick` no seu elemento de exclusão chamando uma função do JS passando como parametro o `ID` do banco de dados.

Nessa função, implemente a função do AJAX para excluir.

Exemplos de AJAX com JQUERY:

```
    $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "delete_usuario.php",
     data: { id: id_requisicao }
    }). done(function(msg){
     alert('Mensagem de sucesso')
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, msg){
     alert(msg);
});
```

Com isso, o link delete_usuario.php será requisitado, porém sem atualizar a pagina.